# How to convert png image into base 64 format in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, base64, qimage, qbytearray

I want to convert a "sky.png" image into base 64 format in cpp using Qt. I found the following code in Qt documentation, but don't get how to get the base 64 format. How to convert image into base 64 format?

```
QImage image;
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG");
qDebug()<<"buffer"<<&buffer;
```

Comment: Try searching again with something more general like *convert file to base64 C++*.

Comment: https://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/06/16/how-to-convert-data-tofrom-base64-in-qt/

Comment: please add any pertinent code to your question as formatted code. Putting it in the comments is an eyesore and more likely to be missed.

Comment: Please share the sky.png or source.

Answer (score 1):

Bro, you are almost there:
you just need to:
write the image into the buffer and then from the buffer get the data as Bse 64...

like:

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QImage qp(":/resources/images/foo.png");
qp.save(&buffer, "PNG");
QString encoded = buffer.data().toBase64();
```

Comment: I tried above example and print the string "encoded". But it seems empty, nothing is printed in debug log

Comment: i think your image is broken... corrupt or non correct formated

Comment: I tested image on online tool, it converted on online in base64 format